# Data Frame operation in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, logic

I have Input DataFrame given below. For every first unique element row of`ID` it has to be written zero in the Output DataFrame `Zeros_For_UniqueID` column. After then the consecutive zeros should be counted from the`Count` variable before the integer appear for the unique `ID`and have to be put in output column `Zeros_For_UniqueID`.

Input DataFrame:

```
ID  Count
1234    1
1234    2
1234    0
1234    0
1234    0
1234    1
1234    1
5678    1
5678    5
5678    4
5678    0
1111    0
1111    0
1111    1
1111    2
1111    0
1111    0
1111    2
```

Output DataFrame

```
ID  Count   Zeros_For_UniqueID
1234    1   0
1234    2   0
1234    0   0
1234    0   1
1234    0   2
1234    1   3
1234    1   0
5678    1   0
5678    5   0
5678    4   0
5678    0   0
1111    0   0
1111    0   1
1111    1   2
1111    2   0
1111    0   0
1111    0   1
1111    2   2
```

Can anyone help me in solving this. I am new to the python and trying to solve this for my further research.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the speed, but this will achieve what you need , you need `groupby`+`cumsum`+`shift`

```
df['New']=df.groupby('ID').\
     apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x.Count.ne(0).cumsum().shift().fillna(False)).cumcount()).\
       sort_index(level=1).values
df
Out[323]: 
      ID  Count  New
0   1234      1    0
1   1234      2    0
2   1234      0    0
3   1234      0    1
4   1234      0    2
5   1234      1    3
6   1234      1    0
7   5678      1    0
8   5678      5    0
9   5678      4    0
10  5678      0    0
11  1111      0    0
12  1111      0    1
13  1111      1    2
14  1111      2    0
15  1111      0    0
16  1111      0    1
17  1111      2    2
```